# Angularjs show chat notification in all pages

Tags: angularjs, notifications

I have created a simple chat application in `Angularjs` using `pubnub`.

I would like to notify the user if a new message is received, right now I can notify the incoming messages only if the user is in the `chat` view.

I need to show the notification even if the `chat` is not in view.

I can use `$rootScope.$on` in all my `controllers` to listen the callbacks and then show the notification.

But I would like to know if there is any other efficient way.

I am using `angular-toastr` to show the notifications.

Comment: I've implemented a very similar feature a couple of months ago and our team used $rootScope. I think its the best way to share info across the application, unless you can use a service that triggers every time a controller is loaded.

Comment: What you are recommending seems just fine.